# How to remove form border and shadow on Wordpress login page?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shadow

I'm editing the Wordpress login page and it is going pretty good so far. I created a separate css file to do so and everything is working as it should except one thing.
I am unable to remove the border and box shadow from the form. I tried this:

```
#login form {
background: #7554a5;
border: 0px !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px !important;
box-shadow: 0px !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried to look in the Wordpress's wp-admin.css to find how the box shadow is applied but I cannot find it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
box-shadow: none !important;
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You dont need important. Just put your css after wordpress one.

```
border: none !important
```

However you should check in firebug or chrome dev tools in css tab how your css gets overided.

Comment: And I wrote "I tried NONE with and without !important;" :) I meant I tried both border: none !important; and border:none;